# add a class to font inside a div with a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have following html rendered in power portals and it is causing to break the formating of the input group.

```
<div class="control">
    <div class="input-group" role="none">
       <font size="3" style="position: relative;">
          <input name="ctl00$ContentContainer$WebFormControl_3596f2cdce74ec11894300224812"....>
       </font>
    </div>
<div>
```

I have tried adjusting in dev tools and if I found that if apply a class of "input-group" to the font attribute everything formats nicely if it is like below.

```
 <font size="3" class="input-group" style="position: relative;"></font>
```

I am not sure how to find the font attribute in dom using jQuery.
I have tried this below but it seems to not do anything

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#WebFormPanel').each(function(e) {
    let divinputgroup = $(this).find("input-group");
         if(divinputgroup.length){
            $("font").addClass("input-group");
         }
    })
 });
```

Comment: `$('#WebFormPanel').each()` makes little sense to begin with, since IDs must be unique within a document.

Comment: the font ELEMENT (is not an attribute) is deprecated and very weird when css is involved. But if you needed a css selector to get that element, it was as easy as `.control font`

Comment: Why loop over anything to begin with? `$('#WebFormPanel .input-group font').addClass('input-group');` should do the trick.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita.. yeah I agree but that is what it generated in dynamics portals and I dont't have any control on how it renders.

Comment: `$(this).find("input-group")` - Looks like a typo in the class selector?  (Missing the period at the beginning.)

Comment: @David that's an error but his whole strategy was far too much to add a class to such element. To get those elements, a css selector is more than enough... but a css rule alone would be much better than using javascript unless you are injecting javascript to a response you cannot control

Comment: @DiegoDeVita yes I have to inject javascript in the response.

Comment: Are you saying you can't change your `.css` files?  You don't have a `page.css` or `site.css`?   `.input-group > font { ..copy input-group css here }`  JS solution will always give FOUC

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for pointing that out, I suppose I could edit the css as well in portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#WebFormPanel').each(function(e) {
    let divinputgroup = $(this).find(".input-group");
         if(divinputgroup.length){
            $("font").addClass("input-group");
         }
      })
  });
```

You can use this and also you can give class to font, so that it can be use easily

Comment: `$('font')` is selecting any font element disregarding its parents... maybe you should be more specific than that? the condition checking if `.input-group` exists isn't very much correlated to the next logic and not enough of a grant to go ahead. It was enough to just directly select the targets and perform your logic on those results if any